# Syntax error on put_line

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am doing an assignment, and am trying to get this to work:

```
declare sal number;
begin
sal := 1;
select min_salary into sal from jobs where job_ID = 'ad_vp';
dbms_output put_line('value is' || sal);
end;
```

If this was mssql, i'd never be asking this, but my studies uses oracle for this semester. Why do I get this error message, and how do I avoid it?

```
> ORA-06550: line 5, column 13: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol
> "PUT_LINE" when expecting one of the following:
> 
>    := . ( @ % ; The symbol ":=" was substituted for "PUT_LINE" to
> continue.
> 3. sal := 1;
> 4. select min_salary into sal from jobs where job_ID = 'ad_vp';
> 5. dbms_output put_line('value is' || sal);
> 6. end;
```

Comment: Did you just move your answer to a comment?

Comment: Yes, but it's back now. I thought I saw another syntax error... Guess not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a dot, it should be:

```
dbms_output.put_line('value is' || sal);
```